# How to make a portfolio neutral to a Fama-French factor?

Tags: beta, fama-french

I have quintiles of 58 companies each that I have performed a CAPM regression with. I now wish to try and make these quintile portfolios neutral to Fama-French factors and was hoping for some insight as to whether or not I am doing this correctly.

To this end, does this seem to make any sense? First, I will take the monthly factors from the Fama-French library and regress each factor I want to use against my quintile portfolio excess returns. This will give me the betas of my quintiles to the factors regressed against. After, I will use these betas by subtracting from my five quintiles' monthly returns by the returns calculated for the risk factors multiplied by the betas calculated for those factors.

This might sound like a load of nonsense, and it may well be, because I can't find anywhere online that suggests this and I would appreciate any help.

Thank you!